# An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, updates

I'm trying to update (Documents to go Main app) in my device.

When I'm trying to install it an error comes out says `an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed`.

I have root access on my device. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Could it be you originally side-loaded that app from some dubious source, or your update comes from such? One of the two obviously is not from the original developer, hence the signatur mismatch.

Comment: I've Documents to go as main app in my tablet and the Play store is restricted in my country so i'm downloading it from one mobile market and after downloading it gave me that , any ways for solve the problem or deleting the app completely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if there's a signature mismatch and I'm sure the original app comes from a trusted source, I'd doubt the source the "update" comes from: the `.apk` very likely is manipulated, and *might* include malware -- so be warned! I do not know the "one mobile market" you've downloaded it from, so I cannot tell for sure.

If you still want to install the new `.apk`: Yes, removing (uninstalling) the previously installed app and the installing the downloaded version should work. If the first one was installed as a system app, you will need the appropriate system tools to uninstall it (e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)  -- which you then could also use to create a backup *before* removing the app, just in case). Alternatively, if you know the right command line tools, you can do it also via `adb shell`.

As the app in question does not require to be made a system app, installation can be done normally without any root stuff: just tap the `.apk` in your file explorer, and let the normal installer do its job.

After that, watch out for any strange behavior -- just in case the `.apk` introduced malware.

Comment: here's my problem i can't remove the system app it just gives me (Disable App) and when i disable it and trying to install the updated one it says (Enable the package) and when i enable it i turn back to my problem

Comment: Quoting your question: *I have root access on my device.* Pointing to the corresponding part in my answer: *you will need the appropriate system tools to uninstall it (e.g. Titanium Backup* I use TB regularly, so I can vouch for it. Did you try to remove the app with this tool, or with any other such like [NoBloat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tvkdevelopment.nobloatfree)? Sure, Android's own *Settings->Apps* doesn't let you uninstall system apps :)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occur when you use a different key while Generate Signed APK, Note: In order to Update your App you need to use the same **Key password** and **key alias** of your previous version then Generate the Updated Signed APK.

Comment: This site is for end-users of Android not developers. The question is about updating an app that they have downloaded not one they are developing themselves.